# How to find native extension gems installed in ./vendor/bundle with "bundle doctor"

Tags: ruby, docker, bundler

We use a Docker image to run CI builds. The Docker image has a system-installed Ruby. The Docker container has the content of [`gem env`](https://gist.github.com/leondmello/0950f8195a447f7a990fe54ab7e59c33#file-docker_gem_env-bash) and [`bundle env`](https://gist.github.com/leondmello/0950f8195a447f7a990fe54ab7e59c33#file-docker_bundle_env-bash) as indicated in the gist linked files:

```
[root@045ce9939883 code]# which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
[root@045ce9939883 code]# ruby -v
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]
[root@045ce9939883 code]# bundle -v
Bundler version 2.0.2
```

We ran the following commands in the Docker container to install the gems at `./vendor/bundle`:

```
bundle config --local path vendor/bundle
bundle install --jobs 5 --retry 3
```

We then tarred the entire directory, including `./vendor/bundle` so that we can deploy the contents later using `capistrano`. On the deployment machines, we first untarred the tar file and then ran the `cap deploy` commands.

`bundler` on the deployment machines can't seem to locate gems which are built with native extensions in `./vendor/bundle`. It seems to find all the other gems just fine:

```
[jenkins@tel-web-sob-r01-n01 2.1.10]$ bundle doctor
The following gems are missing
 * nokogiri (1.10.9)
 * nio4r (2.5.2)
 * websocket-driver (0.7.2)
 * bindex (0.5.0)
 * byebug (9.0.6)
 * puma (3.9.1)
 * ffi (1.9.18)
Install missing gems with `bundle install
[jenkins@tel-web-sob-r01-n01 2.1.10]$ ls -l ./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/ | grep nokogiri
drwxr-xr-x 7 jenkins jenkins  157 Jun 22 13:05 nokogiri-1.10.9
```

The deployment machine's [`gem env`](https://gist.github.com/leondmello/0950f8195a447f7a990fe54ab7e59c33#file-deployment_gem_env-bash) and [`bundle env`](https://gist.github.com/leondmello/0950f8195a447f7a990fe54ab7e59c33#file-deployment_bundle_env-bash) contents are as linked

What I know so far:

1. I found that all the extensions are installed in `./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/`. If I rename that directory to `2.5.0`, it works.
2. Might be related to this [issue](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1387#issuecomment-621630886).

Comment: So I found that all the extensions are installed in `./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/`. If I rename that directory to `2.5.0`, it works.

Comment: Might be related to this issue. https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1387#issuecomment-621630886

Comment: Your comment about renaming to 2.5.0 needs to be in your question, not in a comment. Comments are for us to ask, and suggest things that don't constitute an answer. Your responses need to be incorporated into the question, added as if that information had always been there, paying attention to readability. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags as we can see what's changed. Answering questions or adding additional information in comments forces us to read every comment and try to piece together the information to make sense, so use the question itself.

Comment: Makes sense, will update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Dockerfile` with which we are setting up ruby & bundler is similar to [this one](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/1f19e5d966aadfaac7ce4a9d4db8f982db2fe690/2.2/Dockerfile#L34).

The machines where we deploy the bundled gems are RHEL machines and install ruby from the software collections repositories.

It seems like the deployment machines ruby is built with the `--enable-shared=yes` flag.

We changed our `Dockerfile` to configure the ruby build the same way, `./configure --enable-shared=yes`. That solved our issue.